# Загрузка файла в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Доброго времени суток. Есть проблема: я создаю плагин для Вордпресса. В функционале плагина есть момент загрузки файла в указанную директорию при редактировании поста и, соответственно, прикрепление файла к посту. Примерный код (все внутри класса):

```
add_action('save_post', array(&$this, 'savePostIcon'));
function savePostIcon($id){
    $opts = $this->getOptions();
    //var_dump($_FILES); - пусто
    if(isset($_FILES['myplugin'])){
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myplugin']['tmp_name'], $opts['path'].$_FILES['myplugin']['name'])){
            add_post_meta($id, 'posticon_icon', $_FILES['myplugin']['name']);
        }
    }
}
```

Через $_FILES файл не отправляется. А как тогда его залить в определенную в настройках плагина директорию?
Заранее спасибо.

П.С.: enctype у формы не стоит. Что в таком случае можно сделать, кроме впиливания в свой шаблон javascript'а для загрузки файла?

Comment: стесняюсь спросить - enctype у формы стоит? =)

Comment: Блин, нет. =/  
А как тогда быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообщем нужна вот такая вот формочка:

```
<form id="mypluginForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myplugin">
</form>
```

Если, например, форма уже есть, но нет возможности поправить ее в шаблоне - enctype можно добавить с помощью javascript.

```
onload = function(){
     document.getElementById("mypluginForm").enctype = "multipart/form-data";
}
```

ну а если есть возможность поправить шаблон - поправляем и все =)

Потом, если файл будет загружен - он будет доступен в `$_FILES['myplugin']`

Comment: Супер, спасибо).

Comment: всегда пожалуйста =)

Answer (score 2):

Или в файле плагина

```
// Добовление к форме multipart/form-data
add_action('post_edit_form_tag' , 'add_form_tag');

function add_form_tag()
{
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
```